# No Internetconnection when when service is running (with activity stopped)

Tags: android, service

I already used google to find a solution, but i found nothing.
I have a service that runs independend from the activity, but if the activity is paused/stopped the service can not make a connection to the Internet.
I use a Thread to tell me the state of the connection, and when the activity comes back to the front it works all fine.

Also with a IntentService it has the same Problem.

Here is my Service (shrinked to the improtant parts):

```
public abstract class WakeAndRunService extends IntentService
{
public WakeAndRunService(String name)
{
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/** Has to return a notification that this Service will show when running */
protected abstract Notification setNotification();

/** will be called on onStartCommand to execute stuff*/
protected abstract void startStuff();

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    log("16", "-> WAR_Service: OnStartCommand ",1);
    if(intent == null)
    {
        log("16", "WAR_Service: ####### ERROR: intent = null",1);
        return 0;
    }
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmIntent = new Intent(this, TaskRun.class); 


    //Wichtig damit Service nicht nochmal ohne intent bei Main onDestroy(oder so) gestartet wird
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT; 
}


//Notification setzen, welche auch wieder die Activity startet
private void showNotification() 
{
    notification = setNotification();
    if(notification == null)
    {
        log("16", "WakeAndRunService ERROR: notification = null",1);
    }

    // Send the notification.               
    mNM.notify(notificationID, notification);

    //wichtig, damit Service gestarted bleibt!!!!
    startForeground(notificationID, notification);
}


public void startWakeAndRunService()
{
    showNotification();

    //alarmintent = TaskRun.class
    alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

}

public static void stopWakeAndRunService()
{    
    cancelAlarm();

    cancelNotification();
}


private static void cancelAlarm() 
{
    if(alarmMgr != null && alarmPendingIntent != null)
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmPendingIntent);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    log("16", "-> WAR_Service: onDestroy",1);
    //TODO: check ob stopWakeAndRunService() hier hin?
}
```

}

The Service is started with this:

```
sIntent = new Intent(this, LoadService.class);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, sIntent, 0);
pIntent.send();
```